# Flask request.get_json() возвращает None

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask

Спасайте. `request.get_json()` возвращает `None`. Я просто в отчаянье. В интернете ничего не помогло. + делал по шаблону, как в видео. Но у человека возвращается верный результат, а у меня - `None`. Спасибо большое заранее!

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался. Отныне, чтобы не возвращался **None**, ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ставьте параметр **force=True**.

```
request.get_json(force=True)
```

Comment: А что с этим параметром вместо None вернулось?

Comment: Принимает JSON и преобразует. Суть та же, что и у json.loads()

Comment: тут https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/wrappers.py#L59 написано `:param force: Ignore the mimetype and always try to parse JSON.` у вас заголовок запроса `Content-Type` точно `application/json`? Если нет, то `None` вернется. Проверкой содержимого тела занимается эта функция https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/wrappers.py#L29

Comment: Вот сейчас у меня с этим морока. Тестил через POST на Постман передавая JSON-формат. Работает. А мне нужно получить из form в html JSON и вытащить его в Python. Пока безуспешно. Хоть и сделал по этим примерам https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/
вот декоратор:
def processjson():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    return jsonify(data)
На data происходит ошибка, в браузере отображается как "Bad Request
Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: Ну так посмотрите какие заголовки пришли с запросом на сервер или какие отправляли :) Особенно `Content-Type`. Посмотрел по ссылке, но там столько всего, да и нет конкретики от вас... гиблое дело :) Давайте упрощу вопрос, что выводит `print(request.headers['Content-Type'])`. Если ничего нет или ошибка, то что выводит `print(request.headers)`?

Comment: Добрый день. request.headers['Content-Type] возвращает 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' почему-то...хотя выставлено enctype="application/json"

Comment: По крайней мере, сейчас можно быть уверенным, что проблема кроется в html form. Видимо передается неправильный формат. Но решить проблему не получается...

Comment: Ну, я так и думал, что там тип для формы будет, другое дело интересно, что он вообще данные как json при этом сформировал, т.к. данные для `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` никак не похожи на json

Comment: Просто повторил как здесь https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/ Но это не работает. Есть ли у вас предложения, как реализовать формирование формой JSON? ..это кусочек, которого не хватает, чтобы все заработало.

Comment: Я делал такое через javascript+jQuery: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/rumble%20(vibration)%20a%20xbox%20360%20controller/web/main.py#L98 . Там правда ручное составление json для отправки.